# JavaPoet Add Generic Parameter

Tags: java, code-generation, javapoet

How would I generate a method with the following signature?

```
public <T extends MyClass> void doSomething(T t)
```

So far I have:

```
MethodSpec.methodBuilder("doSomething")
        .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
        .addTypeVariable(TypeVariableName.get("T", MyClass.class))
        .build()
```

**EDIT** This is what the above code is generating (I don't know how to add the parameter):

```
public <T extends Myclass> void doSomething()
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Extract the `TypeVariableName` you generate into a variable so you can reuse its value

```
TypeVariableName typeVariableName = TypeVariableName.get("T", MyClass.class);
```

Then add a parameter of that type

```
MethodSpec spec = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("doSomething")
                            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                            .addTypeVariable(typeVariableName)
                            .addParameter(typeVariableName, "t") // you can also add modifiers
                            .build();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass a Generic typed structure, use the follow way.

```
MethodSpec loadListInteger = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("loadListInteger")
                    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                    .returns(void.class)
                    .addParameter(ParameterizedTypeName.get(List.class, Integer.class), "list")
                    .build();
```